# How to claim the subspace $AB-BA$ has dimension $n^2-1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

There is a problem given in LINEAR ALGEBRA by  HOFFMAN & kUNZE PAGE $107$,

Show that the trace functional on squre matrices of order $n$ is characterized in the following sense:
If $W$ is the space of size $n$ matrices over the field $F$ and if $f$ is a linear functional on $W$ such that  $f(AB)=f(BA)$ for each $A$ and $B$ in $W$, then $f$ is a scalar multiple of the trace function.

MY TRY: Put $C=AB-BA$. Clearly $\operatorname{Tr} C=0$.

I claim that dimension of the subspace of such $C$ is $n^2-1$. So by the rank-nullity theorem $$\dim \ker f +\dim\operatorname{Im} f=n^2$$ i.e $n^2-1+\dim\operatorname{Im}=n^2$ ( as $f(C)=0$).

Hence $\operatorname{rank} f=1$.

Now since trace functional satisfies such $f$'s and it's scalar multiple is also a subspace of dimension $1$, $f$ needs to be scalar multiple of $\operatorname{Tr}$.

MY PROBLEM: I claimed that subspace (the terrible fact is I'm not sure whether it's a subspace or not, can't prove it) of the matrices of the form $AB-BA$ has dimension with $n^2-1$. It means that there is no restriction on the entries of $AB-BA$ except the fact that their trace is $0$. How can I prove it?

Any other approach or hint to solve that problem will also help me. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Please see the link given in the (solution)  for the following post. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007473/determining-the-dimension-of-span-ab-ba-a-b-in-m-n-times-n-mathbb-r

Comment: Don't you mean $C = AB - BA$ after the words "MY TRY:"? Cheers!

Comment: Sorry1let me edit

Comment: Buried in [this past thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/104854/11619) we also have a proof for the fact that all trace zero matrices are linear combinations of commutators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We claim that $\{AB - BA : A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})\} = \{A \in M_n(\mathbb{C}), \operatorname{Tr }A = 0\} = \ker \operatorname{Tr}$.

We already know that $\{AB - BA : A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})\} \subseteq \ker \operatorname{Tr}$.

Let $E_{ij}$ denote the matrix with $1$ at the position $(i,j)$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Check that $B = \{E_{ij} : 1 \le i, j \le n, i\ne j\} \cup \{E_{ii} - E_{nn} : 1 \le i \le n-1 \}$ is a basis for $\ker \operatorname{Tr}$.

For $1 \le i, j \le n, i\ne j$ we have

$$E_{ij} = E_{ik}E_{kj} - E_{kj}E_{ik}$$

where $k$ is some index $\ne i,j$. To see this, let $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{C}^n$ and note that $E_{ij}e_j = e_i$ and $E_{ij}e_r = 0$ for $r \ne j$. Now verify that

$$(E_{ik}E_{kj} - E_{kj}E_{ik})e_r = 
\begin{cases}
0, &\text{if } r \ne j,k\\
E_{ik}E_{kj}e_j = E_{ik}e_k = e_i, &\text{if }r = j\\
-E_{kj}E_{ik}e_k = -E_{kj}e_i = 0, &\text{if }r = k\\
 \end{cases}$$

For $1 \le i \le n-1$ we have

$$E_{ii} - E_{nn} = E_{in}E_{ni} - E_{ni}E_{in}$$

Indeed

$$(E_{in}E_{ni} - E_{ni}E_{in})e_r = 
\begin{cases}
0, &\text{if } r \ne i,n\\
E_{in}E_{ni}e_i = E_{in}e_n = e_i, &\text{if }r = i\\
- E_{ni}E_{in}e_n = -E_{ni}e_i = -e_n, &\text{if }r = n\\
 \end{cases}$$

Therefore $B \subseteq \{AB - BA : A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})\}$ so we conclude $\ker \operatorname{Tr} \subseteq \{AB - BA : A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})\}$.

Comment: I am trying to understand your answer.How did you space in my question in nice way?I haven't learn Latex properly.

Comment: @SubhajitSaha You can see the Latex code if you try to edit my post, or you can mouse over the formulas and right click, and then select  Show Math As $\to$ TeX Commands.

Comment: It isn't obvious that matrices of the form $AB - BA$ form a subspace.

Comment: @ChristianSykes True, this proof only works if we know that it is a subspace.

Comment: @mechanodroid I can't understand why your are saing the matrices of the form $AB-BA $ may not be a subspace ? You have proved it as a subspace $KerTr $. So obviously a subspace.

Comment: @SubhajitSaha Yes, but notice that in this proof I'm already using that it is a subspace. Namely, I only proved that $B \subseteq \{AB - BA : A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})\}$. Since I knew it is a subspace, i said $$\ker \operatorname{Tr} = \operatorname{span} B \subseteq  \operatorname{span} \{AB - BA : A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})\} = \{AB - BA : A,B \in M_n(\mathbb{C})\} $$